# SweetAlert | Сдвиг влево

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

Когда использую этот код

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin-right: calc(-1 * (100vw - 100%));
}
```

При открытии модального окна в SweetAlert, вся страница кроме модального окна сдвигается влево.
Что делать?

Comment: добавить сдвиг не всему `html` а только вашему модальному окну

Comment: Наоборот, я этот код добавил для того, чтобы во время того, как у меня прогружаются объекты на странице и у меня не появился скроллбар - у меня не сдвигался весь контент, позже, когда он появится, например в шапке. Но вот что делать с модалом я без понятия

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.swal2-shown.swal2-height-auto {
    padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Лично мне это помогло